# How did Arandis recognize Jadzia as Dax?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In Star Trek: DS9 (Season 5, Episode 7, "[Let He Who Is Without Sin...](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Let_He_Who_Is_Without_Sin..._(episode))"), Worf and Jadzia visit the pleasure planet of Risa for a vacation. While there, one of Kurzon's old lovers (Arandis) recognizes Dax and they exchange pleasantries - and near the end, Arandis says

> "It's so good to see you again, Dax. Your new host is very attractive."

Without having seen Jadzia before, how did she know that Jadzia was Dax?

I want to say that this has happened in the series on more than one occasion, but I don't have the references. (I know that Kurzon had a high reputation with the Klingons, but I seem to remember that they were told of Jadzia's "Dax" identity - but I might be remembering incorrectly. I figure that other Trill (like Dax's ex-wife, I can't remember the host name) don't necessarily count as they might have a way of recognizing, or at least being privy to, the fact. I'm trying to think of some other examples.)

Comment: She was probably Facebook-stalking her ex.  :)

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Hah, don't think I'd mind the attention from the former Miss America. On a stranger note....social media in the 24th century must be completely *awful*. Holo-ads, holo-spam...

Answer (score 3):

There's no specific explanation given in [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/505.txt), however it's noteworthy that Arandis is described as...

> *...the **Head Facilitator of Temtibi Lagoon**, which makes her something
>   of a High Priestess for Risa's sybaritic lifestyle.*

Since Arandis knew that Dax was coming (and was looking out for her) and given that Jadzia has apparently had no contact with her prior to arriving, this leads me to the conclusion that Arandis noticed that there was a Trill national called 'Lieutenant *something* Dax' on the register of arriving Federation guests from and simply worked it out for herself when she saw a guest who was **about the right age**, with **Trill spots**, **standing next to a Starfleet officer.**

Comment: Not that there haven't been non-Trill officers named Dax before (ST:VI).

Comment: Indeed. That being said, Jadzia hasn't been especially secretive about her past lives, unlike other Trill.

Comment: @Xantec *Crewman* Dax wasn't an officer.